# XPages setfield from view selection

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a repeat control with buttons to select or deselect various docs - that works and I can identify each selected doc by the doc id. I have another button with the following SSJS.  For the docs selected I want to set a field in the underlying doc.  This script works if I do a simple doc.removePermanently(true)... but not if I try to manipulate a common field value for the selected docs.  I'm getting an Error 500 HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception.  What is the proper way to do this?

```
var docsForAction = sessionScope.get("myList");
var doc:NotesDocument;
for(i=0; i < docsForAction.length; i++){
    doc = database.getDocumentByUNID(docsForAction[i]);
    doc.setValue("Level","10");
    }
docsForAction = [];
viewScope.put("myList", docsForAction);
context.reloadPage();
```

Comment: You did not save your change by doc.save();

Comment: I removed doc.save(); in testing... but with or without same error.

Comment: Try using `doc.replaceItemValue("fld", "val")` instead of `doc.setValue()`. Don't think that method exists on a NotesDocument.

Comment: Follow Marks advice. Also make sure to use XPages Log File Reader for easy access to your XPages error logs. They contain more details for your error.

Comment: Thank you... doc.replaceItemValue("Level", "10") did the trick in place of doc.setValue().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting an error 500 because you don't have an error page defined. Go to Xsp Properties and tick "Display default error page". You will then get a more meaningful error page displayed.

The error you'll see is probable on the setValue() line, the message being "null". That's because setValue() is not a method of NotesDocument, it's a method of the dominoDocument datasource (the "NotesUIDocument" XPages equivalent, if you know LotusScript).

Casting the variable (adding ":NotesDocument") is good because it allows you to take advantage of the typeahead support in the SSJS editor or the source pane. That will give you a list of valid methods and the valid parameter types taken.

Comment: Thank you for Paul the suggestions... all very helpful.  Using the method replaceItemValue("field","value") solved my problem.